# Checking if textbox has value

Tags: javascript

How can I make syntax of checking if a textbox has a value using if else statement.
Something like this:

```
if ( //textbox has value ) {
  //perform this task
}
```

Can anyone help please? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you identify the `input` (there's **no such thing** as a 'textbox')?

Answer (score 1):

Give the text box an id, then use `document.getElementByID(yourIDHere).value!=""`

Answer (score 0):

```
var textBox = document.getElementById('textBox');

if(textBox.value != "")
{
    //perform task
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
  <input type="text" id="txtbox" name="txtbox"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var t=document.getElementById('txtbox').value;

       if(t!="")
        {
           //perform task
        }

  </script>
```

JQUERY

```
  $(function(){

       if($('#txtbox').val()!="")
      {
        //perform task
      }

   });
```